# IE long link wrong break

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

Has anyone any idea how to prevent IE(7) wrong breaking urls?

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/uQcj5/5/

The problem is that IE breaks url inside words, like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/que
stions/
```

Comment: Seems to do the same in Chrome.

Comment: Jack, are you sure that you saved your changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620008/ie-long-link-wrong-break'
str = str.replace(/\//g, '/&#8203;');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uQcj5/10/

Comment: @FlashTrava so you could control incoming text after all eh? ;)

Comment: Jack, yep :) This script is great and simple.

Answer (score 2):

You're telling the browser to break in the middle of words, just remove `word-wrap: break-word;` from your CSS.

Comment: It would not help cos' the problem with >long< link.

Comment: Why not? I'm on a mac so I can't test IE, but in Chrome just removing it makes the link stay in a single line (overflowing the div's right border) See http://jsfiddle.net/uQcj5/5/. To prevent the overflow and clip the div's contents, add `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: If you expect the browser to figure out where a word starts/ends inside a link, just forget it. The whole link is considered a single word.

Comment: So I wouldn't be able to see whole link, that's not a solution.

Comment: Well, you may consider javascript and regex to add a `<br>` after some slash, but I think it's too much trouble just to get IE7 compatibility. Regarding Firefox: it's likely a coincidence, make the div smaller and FF will break it too: http://jsfiddle.net/uQcj5/6/

Answer (score 1):

The right CSS to use would be:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

**Edit**

Okay, didn't realize you don't want to break out of the `<div>`. Well, here's a dirty trick for you: add `&#8203;` characters at points where you *do* want to break.

This `&#8203;` character is a [zero width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm).

Comment: So link will break my div, that's not a solution.

Comment: exactly, to prevent when browser will break my link before the last letter for example.

Comment: That's a good solution, seriously, but I can't control incoming text.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `word-wrap: break-word`, add the rule `wbr:after { content: "\00200B"; }`, and insert `<wbr>` at every allowable break point, e.g.

```
<div><a href="#">http://stackoverflow.<wbr>com/<wbr>questions</a></div>
```

The explanation of this (and line breaking issues in general) is a long one, see http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html

Note that if the URL contains a hyphen “−”, extra measures are needed to prevent browsers from splitting the string before or after the hyphen.

If possible, do not use URLs in document content. Use link texts; URLs are primarily meant to be used as `href` and other attribute values, not visible content. Mostly, you should include URLs in the content only if your document is *about* URLs or other technical issues where URLs are really relevant content.